# Creating a stage that points to a glacier vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-glacier

I'm trying to find an easy way to get data from snowflake into glacier to save on storage costs.

But I've been googling around trying to figure out what the url should be to hit our glacier vault. I'm not even sure what to put really, normally for s3 it is just `s3://my_bucket`. Is it the same for glacier?

I'm not even sure if snowflake supports this method, and instead have to do something like snowflake->s3->glacier.

This is what I've got so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE longterm_snowflake_storage_stage
URL='WHT_DO_I_PUT_HERE' credentials=(aws_key_id='', aws_secret_key='')
FILE_FORMAT = my_file_format;
```

Snowflake got back to me, turns out this is impossible. You need to go through s3 as a middle ground and setup something to move it to glacier.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the answer from the question to an answer for closure:

> Snowflake got back to me, turns out this is impossible. You need to go through s3 as a middle ground and setup something to move it to glacier.

Note that if the goal is to "save on storage costs" those will be minimal: You only need to pay for s3 storage during the short time that takes to load the data into Snowflake.

Also when using Glacier remember to factor in the comparably high cost that Amazon charges for accessing the data.